# Angular 12 front end returning encoded get request

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using **mysql** for my db, **spring** for my backend and **angular** for my frontend.  my frontend is throwing this weird bug when its routed proper: [click here to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln059.png)

as you can see, the **path at the end** is `%7Bid%7D` (looks like `{id}` from the backend)

the **http error code** is always one of 3: **400**,**400** or **500**
the **backend** looks okay and I've only really ever gotten this **error code:**

```java
2022-02-04 15:30:31.465  WARN 15200 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{id}"]
```

here is the **controller** in question(a get request):

```java
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/patient")
public class PatientPortalController {
    @Autowired
    private PatientPortalRepo patientPortalRepo;

    @PostMapping("/patientportal")
    public PatientPortal createPatientPortal(@RequestBody PatientPortal patientportal) {
        return patientPortalRepo.save(patientportal);
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("/patientportal/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<PatientPortal> getpatientPortal(@PathVariable Long id){
        PatientPortal patientportal = patientPortalRepo.findByPatientPortalId(id);
        if(patientportal.getId()>0 && patientportal!=null)
            return new ResponseEntity<PatientPortal>(patientportal, HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity<PatientPortal>(patientportal, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }}
```

Some things worth of note that I've **tried** with the backend 
Tried **changing response entity to of type long and returning id**, tried **refactoring the controller** numerous times, tried **changing decorators/paths around**, 20x **checked the types are correct**, **checked if any types other than the id are throwing it**, **checked if I had any security implemented that was denying access**, **checked if adding a onetoone would get it to pop up on the front end**.  It **works fine on the backend**(**returns a list of** what I'd assume is **patientportal object**) but **I am either routing incorrectly**, there is **some security I'm missing**, there is **some type error**, **or** there is **some logic errors**.  **I think** however **the issue lies in the front end**.  
here's the code where I call the front end method **hard coded a value to test**:

```js
this.patientloginservice.loginPatient(this.patient).subscribe(data=>(this.route.navigate(['api/patient/patientportal/1'])),error=>console.log('error'));
```

and here is **where that code is serviced**:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { PatientPortal } from './patientportal';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PatientService {

  private baseURL = "http://localhost:8081/api/patient/patientportal";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getPatientPortalList(): Observable<PatientPortal[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<PatientPortal[]>(`${this.baseURL}`);
  }

  createPatientPortal(patientportal: PatientPortal): Observable<Object>{
    return this.httpClient.post<Object>(`${this.baseURL}`, patientportal);
  }

  getPatientPortalById(id: number): Observable<PatientPortal>{
    return this.httpClient.get<PatientPortal>(`${this.baseURL}/{id}`);
  }

  updatePatientPortal(id: number, patientportal: PatientPortal): Observable<Object>{
    return this.httpClient.put(`${this.baseURL}/{id}`, patientportal);
  }

  deletePatientPortal(id: number): Observable<Object>{
    return this.httpClient.delete(`${this.baseURL}/{id}`);
  }
}
```

any help will be much appreciated, thank you.  again like I said the route routes correctly as far as I can tell, but the rendered table does not fill data and it throws that error.  I am **using a login** that is to **redirect/route** **to** a **patient's details**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Template literals incorrectly.

Instead of just `{id}` it should be `${id}` just like what you did with `${this.baseUrl}`

Hope that solves your issue.